# How can I resolve "Stack Trace Error" in AzureDevOps

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-devops

Im trying to put my ReactJS Github repo on AzureDevOps, I tried the answers of mostly similar questions here, but I cant resolve this error

The error is:

> > Fasto@0.1.0 build /home/vsts/work/1/s
> > react-scripts build
>
> Creating an optimized production build... Browserslist: caniuse-lite
> is outdated. Please run: npx browserslist@latest --update-db
>
> Why you should do it regularly:
> https://github.com/browserslist/browserslist#browsers-data-updating
>
> <--- Last few GCs --->
>
> [2051:0x3641880]   149437 ms: Mark-sweep 1338.9 (1427.1) -> 1338.9
> (1412.1) MB, 1200.7 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.204, current mu = 0.000)
> last resort GC in old space requested [2051:0x3641880]   150646 ms:
> Mark-sweep 1338.9 (1412.1) -> 1338.9 (1412.1) MB, 1208.8 / 0.0 ms
> (average mu = 0.111, current mu = 0.000) last resort GC in old space
> requested
>
> <--- JS stacktrace --->
>
> ==== JS stack trace =========================================
>
> ```
> 0: ExitFrame [pc: 0x262669b5bf1d] Security context: 0x1365b0c1e6c1 <JSObject>
> 1: /* anonymous */ [0x3720c6168e89] [/home/vsts/work/1/s/node_modules/source-map/lib/source-node.js:~342]
> ```
>
> [pc=0x26266b1e9e1f](this=0x0dfd1438d461 ,chunk=0x348a40abacc1 <String[9]: function
>
> > ,original=0x06cf466221e1 )
> > 2: SourceNode_walk [0x2cfbde7159f1] [/home/vsts/work/1/s/node_modules/source-map/lib/sourc...
>
> ```
> FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory  1: 0x8fb090 node::Abort()
> ```
>
> [/opt/hostedtoolcache/node/10.24.1/x64/bin/node]  2: 0x8fb0dc
> [/opt/hostedtoolcache/node/10.24.1/x64/bin/node]  3: 0xb0336e
> v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool)
> [/opt/hostedtoolcache/node/10.24.1/x64/bin/node]  4: 0xb035a4
> v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(v8::internal::Isolate*, char
> const*, bool) [/opt/hostedtoolcache/node/10.24.1/x64/bin/node]  5:
> 0xef7602  [/opt/hostedtoolcache/node/10.24.1/x64/bin/node]  6:
> 0xf06e1f v8::internal::Heap::AllocateRawWithRetryOrFail(int,
> v8::internal::AllocationSpace, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment)
> [/opt/hostedtoolcache/node/10.24.1/x64/bin/node]  7: 0xecfe76
> v8::internal::Factory::AllocateRawArray(int,
> v8::internal::PretenureFlag)
> [/opt/hostedtoolcache/node/10.24.1/x64/bin/node]  8: 0xed06fa
> v8::internal::Factory::NewFixedArrayWithFiller(v8::internal::Heap::RootListIndex,
> int, v8::internal::Object*, v8::internal::PretenureFlag)
> [/opt/hostedtoolcache/node/10.24.1/x64/bin/node]  9: 0xed0cb7
> v8::internal::Factory::NewUninitializedFixedArray(int,
> v8::internal::PretenureFlag)
> [/opt/hostedtoolcache/node/10.24.1/x64/bin/node] 10: 0xe8403f
> [/opt/hostedtoolcache/node/10.24.1/x64/bin/node] 11: 0x112a6cd
> v8::internal::Runtime_GrowArrayElements(int, v8::internal::Object**,
> v8::internal::Isolate*)
> [/opt/hostedtoolcache/node/10.24.1/x64/bin/node] 12: 0x262669b5bf1d
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 1 npm ERR! Fasto@0.1.0 build:
> `react-scripts build` npm ERR! Exit status 1 npm ERR!  npm ERR! Failed
> at the Fasto@0.1.0 build script. npm ERR! This is probably not a
> problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
> /home/vsts/.npm/_logs/2021-12-20T03_49_44_021Z-debug.log
> ##[error]Bash exited with code '1'

The pipeline YML file settings (I put the -g increase-memory-limit because i got an memory error before):

```
# Node.js
# Build a general Node.js project with npm.
# Add steps that analyze code, save build artifacts, deploy, and more:
# https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/javascript

trigger:
- main

pool:   vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- task: NodeTool@0   inputs:
    versionSpec: '10.x'   displayName: 'Install Node.js'

- script: |
    npm install -g increase-memory-limit
    npm run build   displayName: 'npm install and build'
```